# How to get a Python Script from R

Tags: python, r

Here is a working code in R. I want to rewrite it in Python it doesn't seems to work as expected.

```
#KDE
data <- c(65, 75, 67, 79, 81, 91)
plot(NA,NA,xlim = c(50,120),ylim = c(0,0.04),xlab = 'X',ylab = 'K (= density)')
h = 5.5
kernelpoints <- seq(50,150,1)
kde <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  z <- (kernelpoints-data[i])/h
  multi <- 1/(sqrt(2*pi))
  kerneld <- ((multi)*exp(-0.5 * z^2))/(length(data)*h)
  lines(kernelpoints,kerneld, lwd = 3)
  kde <- cbind(kde,kerneld)
}
kde_sum<- rowSums(kde)
lines(kernelpoints,kde_sum, lwd = 3, col = 'red')
grid(20,20)
```

Any Python suggestion?

Comment: try using reticulate package for python/r translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

x = [65, 75, 67, 79, 81, 91]
h = 5.5
kernelpoints = np.arange(50,151)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.NAN,np.NAN)
ax.set_xlim(xmin = 50, xmax = 120)
ax.set_ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 0.04)
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("K (= density)")
kde = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(x)):
    z = (kernelpoints - x[i])/h
    multi = 1/np.sqrt(2 * math.pi)
    kerneld = ((multi) * np.exp(-0.5 * z ** 2))/(len(x)*h)
    plt.plot(kernelpoints,kerneld, color = "k")
    kde = pd.concat([kde, pd.Series(kerneld)], axis = 1)

kde_sum = kde.sum(axis = 1)
ax.plot(kernelpoints, kde_sum, color = "r")
ax.grid()
```

## in R

[image]

## in python

[image]

Comment: Thanks... i didn't came to the idea with **pd.concat** and that is why i just had the small graphs